# Change drupal language from neutral to en

Tags: i18n-l10n

i have a huge drupal website(nodes) and i have to implement a multi language system now it has only one language.

I have installed the i18n module, and set another language but o can`t update the existing nodes from neutral language to EN or RO.

How can i update all the existing nodes from neutral language to EN.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Language Assign](https://drupal.org/project/languageassign) to easily update all the languages of your nodes.

Comment: Thanks f0ns but the modules does not work with drupal7

Comment: If you have the website locally you could test with this query: UPDATE node SET language='en'

Comment: i found something using vbo, i did this update only to a node and seems ok.

Comment: if will not work i wull use the query. You used it before and had no problem?

Comment: Yes I have used it before, if VBO does the trick then that is also a good solution. Here is some extra information in case you are stuck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445636/how-to-change-entity-language-in-bulk